# whenever gem have cronjob on only one machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

We have a large deployment of around a dozen servers. We'd like to use the Whenever gem but I can't figure out a way to say which machine the cron jobs should go on! We only want these jobs to run on our server that does background jobs.

Is there a way to specify this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you deploy the project with Capistrano and you use the default [Whenever recipe](https://github.com/javan/whenever/blob/master/lib/whenever/capistrano.rb), you can create a new Capistrano role

```
role :whenever, "192.168.1.1"
```

and set the role in your `deploy.rb` file

```
set :whenever_roles, "whenever"
```

In this way, the task will be executed only on the specified server.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Didn't know whenever had that option, helps to look at the capistrano file though obviously.

Answer (score 1):

whenever is preconfigured to run against the db role, so if your db role is also the background machine's role you don't have to do the 'role :whenever, "192.168.0.1"' hack.  see the codes

https://github.com/javan/whenever/blob/master/lib/whenever/capistrano.rb#L2