# Whenever gem: cron update in multiple server environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, ruby-on-rails-4.2, whenever

Versions:

```
Ruby 2.3.1 
Rails 4.2.4 
Whenever 0.9.7
```

Our configuration:

[image: Source code deployed on NFS.]

I am able to deploy my application on NFS successfully. Both EC2 instances are mounted on NFS, so both server points to same code. All working fine.

The problem is, as i am deploying on NFS, capistrano-whenvever writes/updates cron on NFS, where no crone is executed as its simple file server.

> I would like to write cron jobs on EC2 instance1  or EC2 instance2.

I have gone through [whenever gem have cronjob on only one machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065109/whenever-gem-have-cronjob-on-only-one-machine?answertab=votes#tab-top), but didn't succeed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

cron update in multiple servers is possible,

Here's [a link](https://medium.com/@mayurpathak888/whenever-gem-cronjob-update-in-multiple-servers-using-nfs-server-ruby-on-rails-836d2d832000)! please refer this link